# Spring transactions - detecting rollback and commit

Tags: spring, testing, transactions

I have methods annotated `@Transactional` and I would like to detect rollbacks and commits.

Does exist any way or any Spring object which can check if transaction was commited or rollbacked?

Answer (score 1):

you can write a unit test cases which is using h2 in-memory database and it will acts like a real db. for example save(obj) and after get(obj).

Also you can write test case which is catch exception that is what you expect(probably when occur a rollback there is also a exception) with this format:
@Test(expected = Exception.class) 
Testclass

Answer (score 0):

just run your `@Transactional` method and then, in another transaction, check what's in db.

and remember to make your tests clean/prepare db before each test (after all the last one could have committed something)